# Analytics.js is it possible to use ga('set') after ga('send','pageview')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I'm running google analytics in the head of the page. For performance I'm loading other code like facebook or jQuery Business Logic async deferred at the end of the body.

Is google universal analytics tracking correctly if ga('set', 'contentGroup1', 'Cat1') or ga('set', 'dimension1',  'customdimension1'); are fired anythere in the body and not before ga('send','pageview')?

Schematic Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        ga('send','pageview')
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ga('set', 'contentGroup1', 'Cat1')
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference) says about set:

> The values that are set will persist with all the **subsequent** send
>   calls for the lifetime of the tracker object.

So it does not work for previous calls to send pageview (which makes sense - per documentation send "sends a tracking beacon to Google’s collection servers" and later method calls cannot modify what already has been sent). While the analytics code is executed asynchronously (which is probably why you are asking) the tracking calls are still executed in the sequence in which they were set.

Comment: Ok so it doesnt make sense how i do it, since the set parameters belong to the page tracking and not to a user or a session. Any clever ideas how to delay execution of the track event?

Comment: ok I cleared that and setting the categories before the page tracking. Data makes now more sence. How is it with custom dimensions e.g. facebook login. I'm loading the facebook lib async defered after the page load to speed things up. This means I will never get the login status before the page track. However this is not a recording per pi the dimension is per unique user. If I set it after the pageview event. Will it be send/stored inside a cookie?